# deleting a selected option from a select box using the "delete" key on the keyboard

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

I am relatively new to `javascript` and need the help of an expert/senior coder.

How do you go about deleting a highlighted/selected value from a select box, so once a selection has been made and I hit the 'delete' key on my keyboard, a `javascript` function will run and delete the selected option from the `selectbox`.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
</head>    
<body>
<select style="width: 250px;" id="list">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attach an event handler to onkeydown, you check for the delete key, you get the current value, you find the option with that value, you remove the option. http://jsfiddle.net/KgPBr/2/

```
$("#list").keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.which != 46) // not delete key
        return;
    var sel = $(this);
    var val = sel.val();
    if(val != "")
        sel.find("option[value="+val+"]").remove();
});
```

**edit** Here's the plain JavaScript version, it may be less compatible with all browser than the jQuery version. http://jsfiddle.net/9cwyx/

```
document.getElementById("list").onkeydown = function(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : event;
    var sel = evt.target ? evt.target : evt.srcElement;
    if(evt.keyCode && evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.which == 46) {
    var val = sel.value;
    var opts = sel.getElementsByTagName("option");
    if(val != "") {
        for(var i=0; i<opts.length; i++) {
            if(val == opts[i].value)
                sel.removeChild(opts[i]);
        }
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: the question is not tagged with jquery

Comment: looks like it works with the help of library of some sort. Is there just a pure javascript way to remove it?

Comment: @Ankit - jQuery is a convenience library on top of JavaScript, it is inface JavaScript.

Comment: @John Smith - Yes you can write a pure JavaScript version, because of the inconsistencies between different browser versions, your pure JavaScript version may not work in all cases, while using jQuery or another similar library will avoid those compatibility issues. I added a "pure JavaScript" version if you check the EDIT to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the below code.  I've used `keydown` event listener.

```
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('keydown', deleteIt, false); 

function deleteIt(event) {
    if (event.which == 46) {  //keyCode of DEL is 46
        var e = document.getElementById("list");
        for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            e.remove(i);  //Used to delete the option
        }
    }
}
```

Check this [**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aDDy2/1/)

Comment: Please share the reason for downvote so that I can learn from my mistakes?